# scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit - optimizer parameters

Tags: python, r, scipy, data-science

Is is possible to manipulate `optimizer`'s parameters when using `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit` e.i. relative tolerances?

In R we can use `control`. How about Python?

```
fitdist(data, "weibull", method="mle", control=list(reltol=1e-14))$estimate
```

Answer (score 1):

The `optimizer` parameter of the `fit` method allows you to override the default optimization function (which is [`scipy.optimize.fmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html)) and supply your own. The callable that you give as the `optimizer` argument must have the signature `optimize(func, x0, args=(), disp=False)`.

To change the default control parameters, you can use a custom `optimizer` that calls `fmin` with additional `xtol` and/or `ftol` parameters.  (Note: You could use a different optimizer instead of `fmin`.)  One that I often use is

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin


def optimizer(func, x0, args=(), disp=False):
    return fmin(func, x0, args=args, disp=disp, xtol=1e-13, ftol=1e-12)
```

For example,

```
from scipy.stats import weibull_min
from scipy.optimize import fmin


def optimizer(func, x0, args=(), disp=False):
    return fmin(func, x0, args=args, disp=disp, xtol=1e-13, ftol=1e-12)


data = [2457.145, 878.081, 855.118, 1157.135, 1099.82]

shape, loc, scale = weibull_min.fit(data, floc=0, optimizer=optimizer)
print(f"shape = {shape:9.7f},  scale={scale:9.7f}")
```

Output:

```
shape = 2.3078998,  scale=1463.7713354
```